# Generating function to change a dollar.

Tags: generating-functions

> Find the generating function G(x) enumerates the number of options to change
> a dollar using an odd number of nickels, a prime number (0 and 1 excluded) of dimes, and any number of quarters.

Here's the generating function I found:
$$G(x) = (x^5+x^{15}+x^{25}+\dots)(x^{20}+x^{30}+\dots)(x^{25}+x^{50}+\dots)$$

Is that look correct? It looks different from the functions that could be reduced as a closed form. In this case we're not adding infinite terms, so should I multiply them out to get the coefficient until $^{100}$? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, the prime part makes it impossible to get a closed form. Quarters and nickels should have a closed form. Your quarters should include the possibility of $0$ quarters, BTW.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thanks! In this case we're not adding infinite terms, so should I multiply them out to get the coefficient until $x^{100}$?

Comment: Since # of nickels required to be odd, # of quarters must also be odd.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks, the highest power of each category should not be greater than 100, is that right?

Comment: Sounds right.  I don't really know anything about generating functions.

Comment: You can cut them all off at $100$, but you don't have to.  Since you're only interested in the coefficient of $x^{100}$ it won't matter if you include higher powers.  There's nothing to gain by including them, though, and I would leave them out.